# horizontal line on a plot with a date axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm keeping track of when and for how long my cats poop in a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("fluffy", "misterCuddles", "senorEsnuggle"))
df$start=as.POSIXlt(c("2014-04-03 23:57", "2014-04-03 23:31", "2014-04-04 00:02"), tz="EST")
df$duration=c(123, 234, 345)
```

Now my `df` looks like:

```
           name               start duration
1        fluffy 2014-04-03 23:57:00      123
2 misterCuddles 2014-04-03 23:31:00      234
3 senorEsnuggle 2014-04-04 00:02:00      345
```

I can plot this like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=start, ymax=start + duration), size=10)
```

[image]

How do I put a horizontal line at midnight, to separate April 3rd from April 4th?

When I try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=start, ymax=start + duration), size=10) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=as.POSIXlt("2014-04-04 00:00", tz="EST"))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error : Invalid intercept type: should be a numeric vector, a function, or a name of a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with a numeric version of `yintercept`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = start, ymax = start + duration), size = 10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(as.POSIXlt("2014-04-04 00:00", tz = "EST")))
```

[image]

PS: I tried `as.POSIXct` versions of 'start' and `yintercept`, but that did not work.